# Why are there two separate development databases, one in rails console and the other at localhost:3000?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I installed postgres then puma for heroku deployment, and now the data available to the `localhost:3000` when spinning up the `rails server` is different in development than the data available to the `rails console`.

As an example, I can go to localhost and create a new post and it works fine, but when I then start the console and look for `Post.all`, I am returned posts from a previous version of the database.

How did they the console and server get disconnected/operating on different databases when they are both in development?

I tried `rails console puma` and got

```
config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:

  * development - set it to false
  * test - set it to false (unless you use a tool that preloads your test environment)
  * production - set it to true
```

So I looked in the config files and saw that they already were all set accordingly. Any insight into what is going on would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In case someone else comes into this difficulty, you start the development database with `puma` as a command instead of `rails s` or `rails server` and then you'll see the rails console is matching the correct database.

Comment: Wait, it doesn't totally work- each window in my terminal seems to spin up a different database.

Comment: Restarting terminal brings consistency.